# Excel, AVERAGEIFS, Date discrepancy

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I would like the average of Column B based on two criteria.  That it happened last year and a text criteria from another column. [Average by year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J1MG.png) In the example I have a Year column for test purposes but I don't want to add it to all the data sheets.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Table1[Unit], Table1[Date], "="&YEAR(TODAY())-1, Table1[Text], "Up")
```

throws a `DIV/0` error.

I believe I need to define the Date range by year.. like `(YEAR(Table1[Date])` but it doesn't work.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Table1[Unit], (YEAR(Table1[Date]), "="&YEAR(TODAY())-1, Table1[Text], "Up")
```

I can get an IF statement to work on a single cell but is there are way to get this to work in a column?

Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **SUMPRODUCT()** function provides some really useful approaches to problems like this.

- In your sample data, the formula `=YEAR(Table1[Date])=2023` should return an array `{FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}`.
- In your sample data, the formula `=Table1[Text]="Up"` should return an array `{TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}`.

**SUMPRODUCT()** allows us to do some interesting things with those:

If I apply a math operation to those arrays Excel automatically converts them to binary;  {0,0,1,1,0,1} and {1,0,0,1,0,0} respectively.  That math function can be doing something like multiplying.  Or if I want to use them as-is in a function I can just use "--" to force a math operation, that makes them negative and back to positive.  In our example we'll be multiplying the arrays so Excel will take care of it for us.

I can do a binary AND operation on the two arrays by using multiplication.  Thus: `= (YEAR(Table1[Date])=2023) * (Table1[Text]="Up")` is actually `{0,0,1,1,0,1} * {1,0,0,1,0,0}` which in turn equals `{0,0,0,1,0,0}`.  And the 1's in this result array represent the rows that meet both criteria.

`=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Table1[Date])=2023) * (Table1[Text]="Up"))` will equal the *count* of rows that met both criteria.  Which is only 1 in your example.

`=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Table1[Date])=2023) * (Table1[Text]="Up" * Table1[Unit]))` is going to sum the result of array multiplication of `{0,0,0,1,0,0} * {4,4,5,5,4,4}`.  In your sample data that results in 5.

So the formula `=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Table1[Date])=2023) * (Table1[Text]="Up") * Table1[Unit]) / SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Table1[Date])=2023) * (Table1[Text]="Up"))` actually is "**sum** of rows that matched" divided by the "**count** of rows that matched".

Notice that a conditional array like `Table1[Text]="Up"` MUST be wrapped in its own parenthesis before it can be added (OR function) or multiplied (AND function) with another array.

You may want to wrap that entire formula in an IFERROR() function so you can display a friendlier message when the count is zero.  For instance:

`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Table1[Date])=2023) * (Table1[Text]="Up") * Table1[Unit]) / SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Table1[Date])=2023) * (Table1[Text]="Up")),"None")`

You will want to fully debug the formula before nesting it in IFERROR() because the IFERROR() function will conceal other errors than just an occasional divide by zero.

This will all seem **very** cumbersome the first few times you use this approach but if you encounter these kinds of criteria problems often in excel, I promise that taking the time to understand SUMPRODUCT() on logical arrays will pay long-term dividends.  Once understood it gives you a robust capability to use SUM, COUNT, and AVERAGE given multiple criteria, that can be any mix of `AND` and `OR` criteria.

Comment: I found this a possibly interesting solution, and I apologize here because I'm dense (like uranium), but the formula returns a #VALUE error.  As I'm unsure the methodology  I'm unsure what to look for.  I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: @Scott, don't apologize, I typed it wrong.  There's an "order of operations" thing you have to be careful about and I wasn't.  You cannot do `( A1:A5 =5 * B1:B5 = "Up")` because the multiplication of `5 * B1:B5` happens first and ruins everything.  The only acceptable for conditional array operations is:   `( (A1:A5 =5) * (B1:B5 = "Up") )`.  I will edit my answer, and then try it again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use formula when defining range so you either have to use helper column or something like this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Table1[Unit],Table1[Date],">="&(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,1,1)),Table1[Date],"<="&(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,12,31)),Table1[Text],"Up")
```

It checks if date is less than 2022/12/31 (`DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,12,31)`)and more than 2022/01/01 (`DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,1,1)`)

Result ((3+7)/2=5):
[image]